# CASE in T-SQL in SQL Server 2005/2008

Tags: t-sql, case

Can you please explain the logic behind this kind of scenario

I have 2 tables

**STUDENT TABLE**

```
CHECK-UP(PK)      STUDENTID            DATE
1001                 1               06/15/1980
1002                 1               07/30/1980
1003                 1               12/28/1980
1004                 2               03/22/1981
1005                 2               01/28/1981
1006                 3               04/20/1981
```

**ACTIVITY TABLE**

```
   CHECK-UP            INDEX              VALUE
    1001                 1                SMOKING
    1001                 2                ALCOHOL
    1001                 3                DRUGS
    1002                 1                SMOKING
    1002                 2                ALCOHOL
    1003                 1                SMOKING
    1003                 3                DRUGS
    1004                 3                DRUGS
```

I was using a simple inner join between the two tables to get all the records which matches the value `'%SMOKING%'`. It gives me 3 rows which has smoking values and the result set will be `1001,1002,1003` and corresponding studentsid will be 1.

What will I have to do to find the smoking information for all the students?

In that case I have to do a left join between the tables first to get all the records but that is not working in my case to include all the students. Please advice. Below is the piece of code.

```
Select DISTINCT STUDENTID
               ,CHECK-UP
               ,INDEX
               ,CAST(VALUE as VARCHAR(MAX)) --CASTING IT SINCE IT IS A TEXT FIELD
               ,CASE
                      WHEN (PATINDEX('%SMOKING%',act.VALUE)) THEN
                             'LMDO'
                      WHEN (PATINDEX('%NOT SMOKING%',act.VALUE)) THEN
                             'LMD1'
                      WHEN (ISNULL(CAST(act.VALUE as varchar(max)),'')='') THEN
                                'CLEAR'
                      ELSE 
                                 'CLEAR'
                  END done
FROM STUDENT stu
LEFT JOIN ACTIVITY act
ON stu.CHECK-UP=act.CHECK-UP
WHERE ??
```

If suppose for `studentID=3` the student has no row for smoking. I want that value to go into the 'CLEAR' bucket. ALSO I cannot put a condition in the WHERE CLAUSE as it will restrict my data. What can be done to resolve this issue?

I expect a result set of something like this:

```
STUDENTID        CHECK-UP         INDEX          VALUE        DONE     DATE
   1               1001             1           SMOKING       LMDO     06/15/1980
   1               1002             1           SMOKING       LMDO     07/30/1980
   1               1003             1           SMOKING       LMDO     12/28/1980
   2               1004            NULL          NULL         CLEAR    03/22/1981
   2               1005            NULL          NULL         CLEAR    01/28/1981
   3               1006            NULL          NULL         CLEAR    04/20/1981
```

Comment: Please add desired results for your example data.

Comment: Start with Dropping the distinct. You are misusing it since what you want is a aggregation (group by) and it's hiding your problem. You need to be more precise about which result you expect. Student 1 can have multiple checkups an each checkup mulitple activities. So student one can have "Smoking", "Not Smoking" and "Clear" in the same set. You will have to define HOW this needs to be aggregated. Once you do that you'll end up with either a group by on your current query or with a subselect

Comment: Smith I have added the desired resultset.

Comment: What is the relationship between `index` and `value`? It looks as though one determines the other so one is redundant?

Comment: yes you are right. 1 is for smoking, 2 is for alcohol, 3 is for drugs. That is all i got in my database.

Comment: You would generally have a separate table mapping the numeric ids to the text descriptions and just store the numeric value in your `activity` table with a foreign key relationship to the other table but not relevant to the question you asked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your example results and original query I assume you need something along these lines.

```
SELECT  S.STUDENTID ,
        A.[CHECK-UP] ,
        A.[INDEX] ,
        A.[VALUE] ,
        CASE [VALUE]
          WHEN 'SMOKING' THEN 'LMDO'
          WHEN 'NOT SMOKING' THEN 'LMD1'
          ELSE 'CLEAR'
        END done ,
        S.[DATE]
FROM    STUDENT S
        LEFT JOIN ACTIVITY A ON S.[CHECK-UP] = A.[CHECK-UP]
                                AND A.[INDEX] = 1
```

Comment: I tried that by putting A.[INDEX]=1 i belive we are restricting the data and the NULL values will not be captured in the resultset.

Comment: @palum - Your query has the filter in the `where` not the `outer join`. For your example data it returns your desired results as [demonstrated here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110268/)